# How to deal with huge amount of fearures generated after applying One Hot Encoding on multiple columns in dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, prediction, feature-selection, one-hot-encoding

I am working on TMDB 5000 movies dataset from kaggle :

```
https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata
```

In preprocessing stage, I used `MultiLabelBinarizer()` in order to encode columns in the dataset like :

```
 - Genres, production_countries, production_companies, Cast
```

Now, I have an enormous amount of features. How to tackle this problem ?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using one-hot encoding, go over your nominal features and select only the values that are frequent enough. You can switch the other values to the string "Other". For example - if you want to leave only the 100 most frequent values:

```
val_freq = df[your_column].value_counts() #finds the frequencies of the values and sorts them
good_vals = val_freq[:100].index #takes the top 100 values
df[your_column][~df['your_column'].isin(good_vals)]='Other' #replaces the values not in the top 100 by "Other"
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, OHE is not the reccomended approach for categorical features with high cardinality. You can use Frequency Encoding for example (also retaining only the most frequent labels like suggested above), or Binary Encoding, or Numerical Encoding.

All these are good solutions that do not create unnecessary many columns in your database!